# phaser-framework javascript "infinite loop" "browser crash" timer

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, phaser-framework

I'm calling this a browser crash, but more like an infinite loop - I'm hardly a javascript expert.  What happens is a game gets to it's end, and the browser (in this case firefox) just goes on and on and on - more like a freeze, no snap, error message, no nothing.  You have to close down the browser completely.  Now the really odd thing about this is this works perfectly fine - off line.  This just happens online.  And the other odd thing about this is that (in the code) the first time it resets the game - this also works perfect both online and off.  Just the second time.
Like this:  (this is part of it)

```
function resetGame(){
  //reset game
```

Ok the above works online and off, player gets dumped out of game, starts over. Then however;

```
function moveToEndGame(){
  console.log("TIMER END");
  var twn = game.add.tween(bg).to({alpha:0},tween_speed,"Linear",true);
  twn.onComplete.addOnce(function(){flagGameover = true;},this);
}



    if(!flagGameover && !star.visible && idx_bullet < bullet_array.length)
    initBullet();
  else{
    if(flagGameover){
      console.log("GOTO GAMEOVER");
      window.location = "../endgame.html";
    }
  }
 }   

}
```

OK, offline it goes directly to endgame.html   online, it freezes up, crashes, infinitive loop, whatever you want to call it.
Anyone have any idea why?
OK, spent hours and hours on this (the  programmer who did this part has since disappeared).  Even went back 2 weeks ago to the code as it was, yup, that does the same thing - infinite loop.
So now I'd like to find a way to just 'abort the javascript' right at the end of the 21 second timer.  I've run across a number of things from other posts such as:

```
// creates a new exception type:
function FatalError(){ Error.apply(this, arguments); this.name =         "FatalError"; }
FatalError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

or

```
function javascript_abort()
```

But....

Even if you throw an exception, it will only kill the current event loop. Callbacks passed to setTimeout or DOM/XMLHttpRequest event handlers will still run when their time comes.

or something with this:
    functions (setTimer and two setIntervals)

OR

```
function clearTimer() {
    clearInterval(intervalTimer);
}
```

Anyway, here are the sections in the code pertaining to the 21 second timer:

var maxTime = 21; //in SECOND
var timerEvent = null;

This is where the timer gets added (after a 3 second animation)

console.log("FINISH ANIMATION and ADD TIMER");

and this

```
     timerEvent = game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * maxTime,   moveToEndGame, this);
    },this);


function moveToEndGame(){
  console.log("TIMER END");
  var twn = game.add.tween(bg).to({alpha:0},tween_speed,"Linear",true);
  twn.onComplete.addOnce(function(){flagGameover = true;},this);
}
```

-----------> and THE END (or supposed to be the end)

```
    if(!flagGameover && !star.visible && idx_bullet < bullet_array.length)
        initBullet();
      else{
    if(flagGameover){
      console.log("GOTO GAMEOVER");
      window.location = "../endgame.html";
    }
  }
  }   

 }
```

So is it possible to kill the timer at the end of 21 seconds and everything else with it and just have the player go to endgame.html  ?????????  i didn't mention the phaser console.log  - can it be done that way? Anyone do something like this before, basically a javascript salvage operation.

Comment: what is in the endgame.html file?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough...  When the game is over, the player is taken completely out of the game and transfered to another html page (endgame.html) by using "window.location"  The problem is....  this works fine OFFLINE, but online, the browser crashes, freezes up, infinite loop?  Not good, don't want to reward the player who has just won, by crashing their browser.

Comment: could you share a minimal example to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Do you know of a more definitive way of shutting down the 21 second timer?  Or could you take a guess?  Or have you ever heard of problems with the phaser-framework console log?                                         the timerEvent = game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * maxTime,      moveToEndGame, this);
    },this);

Comment: I put in an alternate explanation over in Game Development - 'How to stop an animation and a loop in relation to a timer'  Trying to reproduce the issue in this case just isn't realistic, could turn into a swampy quagmire.  Probably looking for a few lines of code and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what it was.

It was missing a callover, as in:

var callGameover = false;

and......

```
   if(flagGameover){
    if(callGameover == false){ 
        callGameover = true;
         console.log("GOTO GAMEOVER");
          window.location = "endgame.html";
```

I didn't know that was enough to cause an "infinite loop" but apparently it was.  Put the above in and loop gone!